# Different kml files for each marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm new to google maps javascript api. I've read some tutorials,and i've faced a problem,for which i can't find an answer.
You can use the feed from a kml file,to show one or multiple markes from the same kml file,like this:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
});
```

But is there a way to represent for each kml file, a marker?

Comment: You want a kml file with only a marker?

Comment: yes,but multiple kml files ,and a marker for each

Comment: You must write several kml file, what's the problem? write kml files for marker?

Comment: using the above code,how it can be done? because using multiple url: parameters, doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load multiple KML files you need to instantiate multiple KmlLayer objects.  The content of the KML (which could be a single marker) will be rendered on your map (assuming you add it to the map, which your posted code doesn't).

Note that there used to be a documented limitation on the number of KmlLayers you could add to a map (based on the URLs of the KML files).  I no longer see that in the documentation, but that doesn't mean it doesn't still exist.

```
var layer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
});

var layer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/another.kml'
});
```

Comment: i've read that is a limit on how many kml layers can be loaded on a map , about 10-20 . is that right?

Comment: That used to be documented and I was going to add a note to that effect, but I can no longer find the reference in the documentation.  I would expect that there would still be a limitation based on the URLs of the KML files included, but can't be sure Google hasn't changed the underlying implementation to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the essenttial code for a KML with a marker

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>test.kml</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name>test</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>19.946565112231001,48.0076404070977,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```